# Hazelcast replace(id, old, new) not calling my MapStore

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I'm trying to implement optimistic concurrency checking in Hazelcast as described [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#optimistic-locking). I've set my MapConfigs to use InMemoryFormat.OBJECT and I've added a version field to my BaseEntity with equals() and hashCode() defined like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this == o)
    return true;
  if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
    return false;

  BaseEntity that = (BaseEntity) o;

  return getId().equals(that.getId()) && getVersion() == that.getVersion();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return (int) (getId().hashCode() + version);
}
```

In my BaseService I've replaced the map.replace(id, entity) with the 3 arg version like this:

```
instance.incrementVersion();
if (getTransactionalMap().replace(instance.getId(), existing, instance)) {

  // do some stuff here
} else {
  throw new OptimisticConcurrencyServiceException(
        "Could not replace existing " + existing.getEntityId() + " with version " + existing.getVersion());
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my MapStore isn't called on updates. In one transaction I create an object and store it to the map via my BaseService.create() method (and this calls my MapStore) then I do some other things with it and call service.update() which ends up calling my doUpdate() method above. This update never ends up getting to my MapStore so the value is never persisted. When I was using the 2 arg version of the replace method (replace(id, entity)) these changes did get to the MapStore and thus were persisted. What's the difference, and how to I get this to work?

EDIT: Adding the update() method:

```
public void update(NestupSecurityContext context, String id, @Validated T entity) throws ServiceException {
  T existing = getOne(context, id);
  if (existing != null) {
    if (existing.equals(entity)) {
      T copy;
      try {
        copy = (T) existing.clone();
      } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        //shouldn't be possible
        throw new ServiceException(e);
      }
      copy.copyFrom(entity);
      doUpdate(context, existing, copy);
    } else {
      throw new OptimisticConcurrencyServiceException(
            entity.getEntityId() + " is out of date! Current version is " + existing.getVersion() + ", trying to save version " + entity.getVersion());
    }
  }
}
```

notes:

1. the equals() checks the version, as above
2. the copyFrom() is because these entities mostly come from REST endpoints and not all values can be set via the REST endpoint. The copyFrom() copies just the editable values, including the version field which has to be carried along when the client calls to get the entity before updating it.
3. the clone() gives us a clean copy of what this transaction reads as the base value

Comment: can you check if you're calling `transactionContext.commitTransaction();` after replace call? I just tried & it seems it's working. Can you share the full `service.update()` method, Hazelcast version & instance type that you're running these operations, client or member?

Comment: Added the update() method. All of the methods in my BaseService and subclasses get the @Transactional annotation applied so transactions automatically open and close at the first service method the thread hits. That's always worked with the old replace(id, entity) version of update. We're on Hazelcast 3.9.2 and Hazelcast is running embedded in the Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with my copyFrom() not calling the parent class to copy the version. I also needed to make my update() methods return the updated instance (which won't be the same as the original instance) so if code needed to keep using the object it could update its reference with the updated object.